# How to allow a user to move a button via iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, move

I'm trying to do something new with my app.

I have a number of buttons that I'd like the user to be able to rearrange on the screen by dragging them. The view is currently created via Interface Builder. The ideal implementation would check for a flag in NSUserDefaults which if present would allow the user to move the object, drop it,then remove the flag which would save the setup for next time the user loads.

Anyone know if anything like this would be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have it done by using the action method -

//called on each instance during a drag event

```
- (IBAction)draggedOut: (id)sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
    UIButton *selected = (UIButton *)sender;
    selected.center = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: This works really nice up to a point, that point being that if the user exits the app the button resets to it's base position. Is there a way that I could adapt the code so that when the user lets go that becomes the new point to load the item in next time the app is run?

Comment: Save the new rect in NSUserDefaults or some local DB so that you can fetch it all time. Save it whenever the button is dragged and load this each time the view is appeared. I am not sure you can save the CGRect object to userdefaults, otherwise save the x and y values of the origin of rect as float values to userdefaults.

Comment: So am I right in thinking using this with an interfac builder created view would not be possible? I have little experience in coding interfaces :-)

Comment: @David26th You can lay out your interface with Interface Builder but then you will have to move your button to its desired position in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: So basically make sure there's an IBOutlet for each moveable element and in my viewdidLoad create the frame based upon stored x/y positions?

Comment: Essentially position with `buttonName.origin.x = 0; buttonName.origin.y = 0;`THough obviously with the 0 being replaced with whatever appropriate value from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble connecting this to my buttons in Interface Builder - sometimes it appears to connect to in the Files Owner, other times it doesn't - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Since `UIControl` is a `UIView`, you can use `addGestureRecognizer` to install on you object a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

A `UIGestureRecognizer` allows a function you wrote to be called each time the specific gesture is executed on the view you attach the gesture recognizer to. You create one like this in your view controller `viewDidLoad` method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     ...
     gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDragOnButton)];
     [button addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
     ...
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This code will instantiate a gesture recognizer and attach it to your button. So, every gesture of kind "pan" (dragging) done on the button will cause a call to `handleDragOnButton`.
In the code above, I assume that you your view controller contains declarations like:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    ...
    IBOutlet UIButton* button;   //-- this is created through IB
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer;   //-- this will be added by you
    ...
}
```

Now, you need define a `handleDragOnButton` in your controller. In this function, you can get the current touch and move the button accordingly by changing its `frame`.

```
 - (void)handleDragOnButton:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {    

        CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {    

            <your logic here>

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {    

            <your logic here>

        }
  }
```

Don't forget to `release` the gesture recognizer in the controller's `dealloc`.

Look also at [this doc from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIGestureRecognizer).

An alternative could be using `UIResponder`'s

```
 – touchesBegan:withEvent:
 – touchesMoved:withEvent:
 – touchesEnded:withEvent:
 – touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

but I would only suggest that if you are targeting iOS 3.1.3 and older.

Comment: Just a comment to say I'm playing with this response also - haven't ignored it but haven't quite got my head around it yet either :)

Comment: Hm, so I've tried decoding this before I ask but two questions remain. Where does the first code piece belong, and secondly would I need to have created my buttons using code rather than interface builder? It's starting to feel like that's necessary to do what I want..

Comment: All the code I gave you can belong to your view controller. I added more details above. Your button/view can be defined in IB.

Comment: Thanks. :-) I think I see how to get it working (away from Mac at the minute) but how would I get it to save the position for the next load up using IB? That's the bit that has me stumped at the minute I guess. Maybe I'm just being daft

Comment: Save the current position with `NSUserDefaults`; then, apply the stored position (if any) to the button in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Cool cool. Shall play properly tomorrow. May I ask - is there any inherent advantage to this answer over the other present, the two seem to do similar things (drag, drop) but with different amounts of code. I presume the extra code gives me something else but due to preparing for a work interview I've not yet had time to fully test.

Comment: `draggedOut` is one-shot, very easy, but less flexible. Think of saving the current UIButton position: in `draggedOut`, you would do that each time the method is fired (that is many times); with my solution you would do that just once in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. In `UIGestureRecognizerStateStarted` you have a chance to save the initial position, in case you have to restore to it (like for a undo, or when cancelling the drag). There could be more examples. In the end, it depends pretty much on you which one is more suitable.

Comment: Ok, that's cool. Last question now I think, I've got a button with an outlet named 'target' how do I set it's position in code manually to override IB? I know I could create a frame for it add as a subview and go that way, but if I'm not mistaken that's going to give me two copies of the same button which is unnecessary for me.

Comment: `target.center = ...` if you want to move the center or define the `CGRect` where you want the button to appear and then do `target.frame = myRect`. ALl this from `viewDidLoad` for overriding well.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out about two seconds after posting. Doh! lol Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is some open sourced code that does exactly that.

https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

"A performant Grid-View for iOS (iPhone/iPad) that allows sorting of views with gestures (the user can move the items with his finger to sort them) and pinching/rotating/panning gestures allow the user to play with the view and toggle from the cellview to a fullsize display."