# Drag UIButton using finger

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I want to move a UIButton in my app using dragging.
The UIButton is created using code.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this in following way:

you can use `touchesMoved` gesture or use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

1) using touchesMoved:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    placardView.center = location;
   return;
}
```

2) using  `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

add a gesture recognizer to the button on `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *objGesture= [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveButton:)];
[myButton addGestureRecognizer:objGesture];
[objGesture release];
```

write the target Method to be called

```
-(void)moveButton:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || 
    recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    UIView *draggedButton = recognizer.view;
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    CGRect newButtonFrame = draggedButton.frame;
    newButtonFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
    newButtonFrame.origin.y += translation.y;
    draggedButton.frame = newButtonFrame;

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
     button.center = pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `panGestureRecognizer` or by using the `touches` methods.
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545047/how-to-allow-a-user-to-move-a-button-via-ios-sdk) for more reference.